# Error establishing a database connection

Tags: apache2, mysql, wordpress

we have wordpress site & everyday we are getting below error :

**error establishing a database connection** almost once i a day

than we have to restart mysql server to fix this....

**var/log/mysql/mysql.log** :

```
180420 15:00:33 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
180420 15:00:33 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
180420 15:00:33 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
180420 15:00:33 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
180420 15:00:33 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
180420 15:00:33 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
180420 15:00:33 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 64.0M
180420 15:00:33 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
180420 15:00:33 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
InnoDB: The log sequence number in ibdata files does not match
InnoDB: the log sequence number in the ib_logfiles!
180420 15:00:33  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!
InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite
InnoDB: buffer...
180420 15:00:33  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
180420 15:00:34 InnoDB: 5.5.40 started; log sequence number 95113383371
180420 15:00:34 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '127.0.0.1'; port: 3306
180420 15:00:34 [Note]   - '127.0.0.1' resolves to '127.0.0.1';
180420 15:00:34 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '127.0.0.1'.
180420 15:00:34 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
180420 15:00:34 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.40-0ubuntu1'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  (Ubuntu)
```

**/etc/mysql - my.cnf**

```
#
# The MySQL database server configuration file.
#
# You can copy this to one of:
# - "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" to set global options,
# - "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
# 
# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.
#
# For explanations see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html

# This will be passed to all mysql clients
# It has been reported that passwords should be enclosed with ticks/quotes
# escpecially if they contain "#" chars...
# Remember to edit /etc/mysql/debian.cnf when changing the socket location.
[client]
port        = 3306
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

# Here is entries for some specific programs
# The following values assume you have at least 32M ram

# This was formally known as [safe_mysqld]. Both versions are currently parsed.
[mysqld_safe]
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice        = 0

[mysqld]
innodb_buffer_pool_size=64M
#
# * Basic Settings
#
user        = mysql
pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port        = 3306
basedir     = /usr
datadir     = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir      = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking
#
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
bind-address        = 127.0.0.1
#
# * Fine Tuning
#
key_buffer      = 16M
max_allowed_packet  = 16M
thread_stack        = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 8
# This replaces the startup script and checks MyISAM tables if needed
# the first time they are touched
myisam-recover         = BACKUP
#max_connections        = 100
#table_cache            = 64
#thread_concurrency     = 10
#
# * Query Cache Configuration
#
query_cache_limit   = 1M
query_cache_size        = 16M
#
# * Logging and Replication
#
# Both location gets rotated by the cronjob.
# Be aware that this log type is a performance killer.
# As of 5.1 you can enable the log at runtime!
#general_log_file        = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
#general_log             = 1
#
# Error log - should be very few entries.
#
log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log
#
# Here you can see queries with especially long duration
#log_slow_queries   = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
#long_query_time = 2
#log-queries-not-using-indexes
#
# The following can be used as easy to replay backup logs or for replication.
# note: if you are setting up a replication slave, see README.Debian about
#       other settings you may need to change.
#server-id      = 1
#log_bin            = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
expire_logs_days    = 10
max_binlog_size         = 100M
#binlog_do_db       = include_database_name
#binlog_ignore_db   = include_database_name
#
# * InnoDB
#
# InnoDB is enabled by default with a 10MB datafile in /var/lib/mysql/.
# Read the manual for more InnoDB related options. There are many!
#
# * Security Features
#
# Read the manual, too, if you want chroot!
# chroot = /var/lib/mysql/
#
# For generating SSL certificates I recommend the OpenSSL GUI "tinyca".
#
# ssl-ca=/etc/mysql/cacert.pem
# ssl-cert=/etc/mysql/server-cert.pem
# ssl-key=/etc/mysql/server-key.pem



[mysqldump]
quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet  = 16M

[mysql]
#no-auto-rehash # faster start of mysql but no tab completition

[isamchk]
key_buffer      = 16M

#
# * IMPORTANT: Additional settings that can override those from this file!
#   The files must end with '.cnf', otherwise they'll be ignored.
#
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
```

when i ran command : `zgrep -a "allocate memory" /var/log/mysql/error.log*` , i got below result  :

[image]

Also i ran **free -m** :

[image]

**mpm_prefork.conf**

```
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
    StartServers             5
    MinSpareServers       5
    MaxSpareServers      10
    #MaxRequestWorkers    150
MaxRequestWorkers 256
MaxConnectionsPerChild 500
    #MaxConnectionsPerChild   0
</IfModule>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

**cat /proc/meminfo** result  :

[image]

Comment: Additional information request, please. Post on pastebin.com or here.
Text results of: 
A) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; 
B) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
C) complete MySQLTuner.com  report
D) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
Optional very helpful information, if available includes -
htop   OR  top for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a linux/unix list of limits, 
iostat -x when system is busy for an idea of IOPS by device, 
df -h  for a linux/unix free space list by device, 
free -m  for a linux/unix free memory report
for HOST server analysis.

Comment: @WilsonHauck thanks for support, once i increased `swap memory`, it worked fine.....

Comment: You had 1G swap memory, what did you change it to?  Glad you are working fine.  If you could up vote my suggestion, that would be great.

Comment: @WilsonHauck changed as  this image : https://prnt.sc/j9dugj

Comment: You are way TOO conservative, go for 12G, to ensure you do not get stalled when swap space becomes necessary.

Comment: @WilsonHauck Thanks for suggestion, i will increase it.... also currently site performance is not good, how much ever swap size i increased also , site will not run fast , right ? it need more RAM right ?

Comment: Not so fast on additional RAM, please post additional information requested and I will assist.

Comment: @WilsonHauck thanks a lot, i will post additional information this week, thanks again for your support.....

Comment: Please open a NEW Question and post the additional information.    When open, send me the link, please.

Comment: @WilsonHauck sure, i will do that as soon as possible..... thanks.....

Comment: Additional information request, please. Post on pastebin.com or here. Text results of: A) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; B) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; C) complete MySQLTuner.com report D) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; Optional very helpful information, if available includes - htop, top & mytop  for most active apps, ulimit -a for a linux/unix list of limits, iostat -x when system is busy for an idea of IOPS by device, df -h for a linux/unix free space list by device, free -m for a linux/unix free memory report for in depth HOST server analysis.